# Execute different command in Inno Setup Run section based on Windows version

Tags: inno-setup

I need to know if the Windows is XP, 7, 8, 2003, 2008 or 2012, because depends on version I will run a specific command.

I tried to install IIS in Windows 2008, but it did not work. I tried in Windows 2012 and it worked normally.

```
Filename: pkgmgr; Parameters: "/iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASP;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-CGI;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-Performance;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-WebServer;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;IIS-ASPNET;NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45;IIS-ASPNET45;IIS-NetFxExtensibility45;NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45"; Flags: 64bit; Check: IsWin64
```

I had to run this manually in Windows 2008:

```
start /w pkgmgr /l:log.etw /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-CGI;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-WebServer;
```

Comment: You can use `MinVersion:` and  `OnlyBelowVersion:`. E.g. `MinVersion: 0,6.1.7600;` for Windows 7 with Compilation Number and `OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.2` for Windows 8 with no Compilation Number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`MinVersion` and `OnlyBelowVersion` parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams) in the [`[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

```
[Run]
; for Windows 2012 and newer:
Filename: pkgmgr; Parameters: "/iu:..."; MinVersion: 6.2
; for older versions (Windows 2008)
Filename: pkgmgr; Parameters: "/iu:..."; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.2
```

Learn [the Windows version numbers](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes).