# Execute different BLOCK of commands in Inno Setup Run section based on Windows version

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I know there is already question [Execute different command in Inno Setup Run section based on Windows version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605614/execute-different-command-in-inno-setup-run-section-based-on-windows-version) with very good answer.

My question is how to perform different blocks of commands for different target Windows versions. My problem is that I have ~10-15 commands that need to perform if target version is Windows 7 and the ~same amount of different commands for Windows 8 or above.

Is it possible to avoid the need to add `; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.2` after each command needed for first case and `; MinVersion: 6.2` after each command in the second block?

I know there is preprocessor conditions `"#if"`, `#else` and `#endif` but that of course works only at compilation time

The question and answers [Determine Windows version in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849917/determine-windows-version-in-inno-setup) although may look similar to this question are NOT answering it. I know how to determine Windows version in Inno Setup. I also know about those `; MinVersion: 6.2` and `; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.2` options. I am asking if it is possible to specify a block of commands (10-15 commands) and apply that option to entire block, not to each and every command individually.

The goal is not to avoid *"cryptic version numbers"* but to avoid **repeating** the same condition many times. And to avoid risk of forgetting it when block will grow over the time.

The solution that I found so far is to use `CurStepChanged` procedure:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
   if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
      if IsWindows8OrLater() then
         MsgBox('Running on Windows 8 Or Later', mbInformation, MB_OK)
         { 15 comands or call of W8-specific procedure goes here }
      else begin
         MsgBox('Running on Windows 7', mbInformation, MB_OK);
         { 15 comands or call of W7-specific procedure goes here }
      end;
end;
```

But it looks a bit ugly to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no block-control features in the `.iss` file.

All you can do, to avoid repeating the cryptic version numbers, is to define a preprocessor variable like:

```
#define Windows8AndNewer "MinVersion: 6.2"
#define Windows7AndOlder "OnlyBelowVersion: 6.2"

[Run]
Filename: "Windows8-Command1.exe"; {#Windows8AndNewer}
Filename: "Windows8-Command2.exe"; {#Windows8AndNewer}

Filename: "Windows7-Command1.exe"; {#Windows7AndOlder}
Filename: "Windows7-Command2.exe"; {#Windows7AndOlder}
```

---

The only other way is to reimplement the `[Run]` section in the `[Code]` using the [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec):

```pascal
procedure Run(FileName: string);
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Exec(FileName, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  { some error checking }
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if GetWindowsVersion() >= $06020000 then
    begin
      Log('Running on Windows 8 or later');
      Run('Windows8-Command1.exe');
      Run('Windows8-Command2.exe');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Running on Windows 7 or older');
      Run('Windows7-Command1.exe');
      Run('Windows7-Command2.exe');
    end;
  end;
end;
```